# Run ncpa.cpl as administrator in command line

Tags: windows-7

I use teamviewer to control my computer remotely, when I tried to opel ncpa.cpl with this command:

```
runas /user:%computername%\Administrator cmd
```

Then type my password, then execute ncpa.cpl, and then network adapter window is opened, but I can't to change ip address, if I tried to change ip address, this message appears "You don't have permission"

Comment: ncpa.cpl opens control.exe which runs explorer.exe and you can't run Explorer.exe as admin, until you allow it with some hacks: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=144776